# From Adjacency matrix to Bipartite Graph in NewworkX

Tags: python, matrix, networkx

I have a csr matrix from which I extracted data, rows, and columns. 
I want to create a bipartite graph using NetworkX, and I also tried several solutions without success (as an example: [Plot bipartite graph using networkx in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829123/plot-bipartite-graph-using-networkx-in-python)). The reasons why it doesn't work, in my opinion, is a matter of labeling. My two sets and the nodes inside them have no string name.

For example in a 10x10 matrix, the rows/cols indexes represent the name of the nodes of the two sets, while the intersection of these nodes is the weighted link between those nodes.

In my case, then, if I have (0,0)=0.5 it doesn't mean that it is a self-loop; instead, the link with weight 0.5 connects the "node 0" of the first set with the "node 0" of the second one.

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(foo, n_row, n_col):
    n_row=10
    n_col=10
```

After the creation of the matrix, I obtain my data

```py
    weights = weights.tocsr() 
    wcoo = weights.tocoo()
    m_data = wcoo.data
    m_rows = wcoo.row
    m_cols = wcoo.col

    g = nx.Graph()  

    # TRIAL 1
    g.add_nodes_from(m_cols, bipartite=0)
    g.add_nodes_from(m_rows, bipartite=1)
    bi_m = bipartite.matrix.biadjacency_matrix(g, m_data)
    # TRIAL 2
    g.add_weighted_edges_from(zip(m_cols, m_rows, m_data))


    nx.draw(g, node_size=500)
    plt.show()
```

I expected a bipartite graph with two sets of 10 nodes per each with a certain amount of weighted links among them (without link among the same set) as a result. 
I, instead, obtained a classic non-oriented graph with 10 nodes in total.

At the same time, I'd like to optimize as well as I can my code to speed-up the computational time without affecting the readability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Networkx bipartite graphs: nodes of different sets with the same number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150408/networkx-bipartite-graphs-nodes-of-different-sets-with-the-same-number)

Comment: The problem you are having is due to using `m_cols` for one set of bipartite nodes and `m_rows` for the other set. Since `m_cols` and `m_rows` both take values from `[0, 1, ..., 9]`, [networkx thinks they refer to the same nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29154229/9235855). You will need to uniquify the names of your nodes.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I solved by adding:

`m_cols_label = ["a" + str(m_c) for m_c in m_cols]`    
`m_rows_label = ["b" + str(m_r) for m_r in m_rows]`  
using both my trials without the line:  
`bi_m = bipartite.matrix.biadjacency_matrix(g, m_data)`  
However, is not this solution quite expansive in terms of computational time because of the for-loops used ? In your opinion, is there any other way to manage this issue?